# is there any way to find the last modified file from a directory in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, file, file-handling

I am trying to find a last modified file( based on timestamp) in **C++.** Suppose there are many files present in a directory but how to get a last modified file?
I have tried using dirent.h but need to include an extra header file and also using stat but in a stat, I can get the only date of a file.
Is there any way to get the names of all files present in a directory and then read one by one?

Can anyone help me out?
A small code snippet would be appreciated.

Operating system: Windows

Comment: You might be able to do this with [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem), if you have C++17 or better. I'm not up to speed on this part of the standard library, though.

Comment: "is there any way to find the last modified file from a directory in C++?" - No, of course not. That's an unsolvable problem. Operating system and file system implementors have struggled with that conundrum for decades. It just isn't doable - it would require timestamps and sorting - technologies we have yet to discover.  *Of course* it is doable!

Comment: @JesperJuhl Doesn't require sorting though. All you need to do is look at each file and remember which one was the latest.

Comment: @eerorika Sure. But I think I still made my point. The comment was not exactly written with 100% accuracy in mind.

Answer (score 5):

> is there any way to find the last modified file from a directory in C++?

Yes. All parts of the solution are in the standard library: You can get a range of files in directory using `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` and you can get the last modified time using `std::filesystem::last_write_time` and you can find the maximum in a range using `std:max_element`.

> but I am using older version [than C++17]

Prior to C++17, interaction with the filesystem was extremely limited in the standard library. This could only be implemented using an API provided by the operating system.

Comment: `std::filesystem` is only available with the c++17

Comment: @thibsc Fortunately, we're in 2020. :)

Comment: Or boost::filesystem here: [https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)

Comment: but I am using older version :(

Comment: @CoderDude Simple.  Get `boost`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie a small code snippet would be appreciated as I am new to file handling.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings of course, just a precision if it is not available for CoderDude

Comment: Since this is tagged Windows, bear in mind that the last-write time in the directory entry is not necessarily current. FAT32 only updates the last-write time from the in-memory FCB of an open file when it's flushed via `FlushFileBuffers`. NTFS is better about synchronizing the FCB to the directory entry, but only when the file is directly accessed (e.g. via `GetFileAttributes[Ex]W`), not from reading the directory. And it only updates the directory entry for the accessed hard link. Timestamps for other hard links can be stale by an indefinite time period (weeks, months) until accessed.

Comment: I checked. With Visual C++, `filesystem::last_write_time` is implemented via `GetFileAttributesExW` instead of reading the directory entry from `FindFirstFileW`, so it should be reliable. :-)

Comment: @ErykSun I think filesystem is in C++17 and I am using older version.